# Sharepoint Document Archive and Management

Tags: sharepoint-server, limitations

I was asked by my manager to look for possible solutions to convert our archive paper file cabinets that are full of student records into digital format. We do not utilize SharePoint yet at the school but I was researching and found that Sharepoint does a good job in archiving and content management. The ultimate goal for us is:

1- To be able to scan the documents in the file cabinets and save them into folders on SharePoint. We want to be able to create a folder under a specific students' name and then scan all documents related to that student into that specific folder.

2- Give permission to specific staff members to access and search for docs by student name.

I wanted to ask if this is possible to achieve by SharePoint knowing that we have an estimate of 120,0000 paper docs to scan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now making expectations we're talking about the SharePoint Server 2013's limitations. 1.200.000 (1.2M) documents is still fine for SharePoint Server. To completely understand the limitations of the mentioned product, have a look at [the official documentation about Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ContentDB).

> The largest number of items per content database that has been tested on SharePoint Server 2013 is 60 million items, including documents and list items. If you plan to store more than 60 million items in SharePoint Server 2013, you must deploy multiple content databases.

The SharePoint is indeed widely used for document management besides its other benefits.

SharePoint also has great user control possibilities and having a folder per user for example isn't a big deal. Permissions are also easily manageable per users or by user groups, such as staff members.